# Deployment with deployment.yaml file

Tags: kubernetes, yaml, continuous-deployment

I have a deployment file that goes through CircleCI for kubernetes that just won't go through no matter what. This is what my deployment.yaml contains:

`kind: Deployment
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
metadata:
  name: usage-metrics
  namespace: foo
  labels:
    foo-app: usage-metrics
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      foo-app: usage-metrics
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        foo-app: usage-metrics
        name: usage-metrics
    spec:
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 60
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: regsecret
      containers:
      - image: foo/usage-metrics
        name: app
        env:
        - name: TEMP_ENV_VAR
          value: "temp"
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080`

For some reason, I keep getting this error when I push it through:

`"STDIN": error validating data: [ValidationError(Deployment.spec.template.spec.containers[0].env): invalid type for io.k8s.api.core.v1.Container.env: got "string", expected "array", ValidationError(Deployment.spec.template.spec): unknown field "ports" in io.k8s.api.core.v1.PodSpec]`

Deploy section of CCI config:

`echo ":: deploying to $CONTEXT"
            export CLUSTER_ID=$CONTEXT
            cd $SOURCE_PATH
            kd \
              --context $CONTEXT \
              --namespace foo \
              --ssh-host deploy@bastion.$CTL_CONTEXT \
              --timeout 8m \
              --images "app=$(cat new-tag)" \
              --file deployment.yaml`

I know for sure that env is an array and not a string so I'm not sure why this is happening, Please help!
Thanks!

Comment: how are you doing the deployment? the yaml is definitely valid

Comment: I'm deploying through circleCi

Comment: yes, but how? post your configuration for circleci

Comment: For some reason it also thinks that ports is a child of spec and not containers

Comment: just edited to add the deploy section of config

Answer (score 0):

The yaml looks valid when pasting it in http://www.yamllint.com/ . Check if something is adding characters or breaking the indentations with the way are using `kubectl` in CircleCI.

Answer (score 0):

So I ended up figuring it out. For some reason CircleCI was checking my code against the master branch (Which was behind). While I was pushing into CCI through another branch that was more updated, it still didn't like that my master branch had a string in the env slot. As soon as I updated that everything worked. Thanks guys!